# iPhone app is crashing on some devices :(

Tags: objective-c, iphone, crash

On our test devices(iPhone 4S,5 and 6 Plus) app is working fine but when i send build to client then app start crashing on 2 out of 4 devices.
Below i paste the crash log from hockey and i am unable to find the crash reason.
Please help me to find the reason of crash.

Thanks

```
Incident Identifier: 64218179-BEF1-47A2-B572-48A7324BA271
CrashReporter Key:   D510E37E-8C56-4E2F-874E-DA0A6484C40B
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,1
Process:         AppName [447]
Path:            /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/44F4B354-F49C-41AF-B600-373703FC523C/AppName.app/AppName
Identifier:      com.AppName.AppName
Version:         1.0.04
Code Type:       ARM-64
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2015-02-17T07:28:16Z
OS Version:      iPhone OS 8.1.2 (12B440)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGTRAP
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x185ac9458
Crashed Thread:  6

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000196a60e7c 0x196a60000 + 3708
1   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000185ba1ed0 0x185ac4000 + 909008
2   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000185b9fe24 0x185ac4000 + 900644
3   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000185acd0a4 0x185ac4000 + 37028
4   GraphicsServices                     0x000000018ec775a4 0x18ec6c000 + 46500
5   UIKit                                0x000000018a4023c0 0x18a38c000 + 484288
6   AppName                              0x0000000100111714 0x100058000 + 759572
7   libdyld.dylib                        0x0000000196962a08 0x196960000 + 10760

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000196a60c94 0x196a60000 + 3220
1   libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000019693b3b4 0x196938000 + 13236

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000196a7bc78 0x196a60000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000196b14fa8 0x196b14000 + 4008

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000196a60e7c 0x196a60000 + 3708
1   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000185ba1ed0 0x185ac4000 + 909008
2   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000185b9fe24 0x185ac4000 + 900644
3   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000185acd0a4 0x185ac4000 + 37028
4   CFNetwork                            0x00000001855d24e8 0x185534000 + 648424
5   Foundation                           0x0000000186abdc0c 0x1869c8000 + 1006604
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000196b17e80 0x196b14000 + 16000
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000196b17ddc 0x196b14000 + 15836
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000196b14fb0 0x196b14000 + 4016

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000196a7b498 0x196a60000 + 111768
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000196b17e80 0x196b14000 + 16000
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000196b17ddc 0x196b14000 + 15836
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000196b14fb0 0x196b14000 + 4016

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000196a60e7c 0x196a60000 + 3708
1   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000185ba1ed0 0x185ac4000 + 909008
2   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000185b9fe24 0x185ac4000 + 900644
3   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000185acd0a4 0x185ac4000 + 37028
4   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000185b1f1fc 0x185ac4000 + 373244
5   CoreMotion                           0x00000001864ca990 0x186488000 + 272784
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000196b17e80 0x196b14000 + 16000
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000196b17ddc 0x196b14000 + 15836
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000196b14fb0 0x196b14000 + 4016

Thread 6 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000185ac9458 0x185ac4000 + 21592
1   AppName                              0x00000001000c43a4 0x100058000 + 443300
2   AppName                              0x00000001000c4044 0x100058000 + 442436
3   AddressBook                          0x0000000184d9f288 0x184d3c000 + 406152
4   TCC                                  0x0000000191bfd6f0 0x191bfc000 + 5872
5   TCC                                  0x0000000191bff528 0x191bfc000 + 13608
6   libxpc.dylib                         0x0000000196b3c6b8 0x196b38000 + 18104
7   libxpc.dylib                         0x0000000196b3c648 0x196b38000 + 17992
8   libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000019693936c 0x196938000 + 4972
9   libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000019694540c 0x196938000 + 54284
10  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000019694675c 0x196938000 + 59228
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000196b152e4 0x196b14000 + 4836
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000196b14fa8 0x196b14000 + 4008

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000196a60e7c 0x196a60000 + 3708
1   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000185ba1ed0 0x185ac4000 + 909008
2   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000185b9fe24 0x185ac4000 + 900644
3   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000185acd0a4 0x185ac4000 + 37028
4   Foundation                           0x00000001869d5804 0x1869c8000 + 55300
5   Foundation                           0x0000000186a2fef8 0x1869c8000 + 425720
6   AppName                              0x00000001000b17cc 0x100058000 + 366540
7   Foundation                           0x0000000186abdc0c 0x1869c8000 + 1006604
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000196b17e80 0x196b14000 + 16000
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000196b17ddc 0x196b14000 + 15836
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000196b14fb0 0x196b14000 + 4016

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000196a7bc78 0x196a60000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000196b14fa8 0x196b14000 + 4008

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000196a7bc78 0x196a60000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000196b14fa8 0x196b14000 + 4008

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000196a7bc78 0x196a60000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000196b14fa8 0x196b14000 + 4008

Thread 6 crashed with ARM-64 Thread State:
    pc: 0x0000000185ac9458     fp: 0x0000000103647bf0     sp: 0x0000000103647b90     x0: 0x0000000000000000 
    x1: 0x000000020000078c     x2: 0x0000000174c40f38     x3: 0x0000000196d3fb00     x4: 0x0000000000000000 
    x5: 0x000000000000004c     x6: 0x0000000000000034     x7: 0x0000000000000000     x8: 0x0000000000000000 
    x9: 0x000001a596f74689    x10: 0x0000000000000007    x11: 0x0000000196f80df0    x12: 0x000000015f0c5000 
   x13: 0x000001a596f74689    x14: 0x00000061c68296e5    x15: 0x00000000000000c8    x16: 0x0000000185ac901c 
   x17: 0x0000000185adea38    x18: 0x0000000000000000    x19: 0x0000000000000000    x20: 0x000000017024bd90 
   x21: 0x0000000000000000    x22: 0x0000000000000001    x23: 0x000000017409ea50    x24: 0x0000000199c69af8 
   x25: 0x0000000170281708    x26: 0x0000000000000000    x27: 0x000000019a5d7080    x28: 0x000000019a5d7078 
    lr: 0x00000001000c43a4   cpsr: 0x0000000060000000
```

Comment: As it is the thread doing something with AddressBook have you checked if you are asking for access to the AddressBook correctly. Also are you handling it if the user denies access?

Comment: Yes, i am checking the AddressBook permission while accessing contacts. If access is denied then i do not perform any action with AddressBook.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the trace it seems that app crashes when you do some address book operations on iPhone 5S ([as per the hockey docs](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x/ios-device-types)) with 8.1.2 OS version

you may ask the client on which module it crashes and what are the steps to produce the crash.

Always give builds to the client which are tested on both latest and lowest version of OS your are supporting, use better crash reporting library which provides complete details of the crash like [crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) (just an example).

We can end up with strange crashes when device is running out of memory that can also be one of the reason.

Comment: iPhone 6,1 is actually the iPhone 5S (internal version number is 6,1) http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x/ios-device-types

Comment: @AdamRichardson : thank you for the corrections i have made the changes in my answer.

Comment: Thanku NSDumb :)
It was AddressBook issue. I want to vote up but unfortunately i don't have sufficient reps.

Comment: @NazrulIslam: Ok no worries :)

Answer (score -1):

Check which devices. What OS version are they running. Whether they are 32 or 64 bits. Find what the working devices and the crashing devices have in common. Then find out how you get symbols for your crash report. As it is, it is absolutely useless.

Maybe something as simple as calling iOS8 methods on an iOS7 device.

Comment: Check the crash log it shows it is iOS8.1.2 and ARM 64 (64 bit) also shows it is iPhone6,1 (iPhone 5S)